# iOS AdMob Mediation Not Working (iAd Never Shows Up)

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, iad

I've completely and properly (to my understanding) setup AdMob mediation so that my iAd will show up before my AdMob ad, and if the iAd doesn't fill then I would like to show the AdMob ad. Thing is, iAd banner never shows up..EVER! If I disable iAd in my AdMob account everything works perfectly and AdMobs show up but I would really like to get both working. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated. (I've followed Googles guide to setting up mediation). Anyone else having this issue?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird solution but it worked:

By following the guide provided by Google to setup Ad Mediation in iOS, it tells you to implememnt it via Storyboard/nib. Once I removed this method and simply implemented the GADBannerView programmatically, everything began to work as expected. Quite the annoying issue, but thankfully it's solved and I can move on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the admob adapter for iAds to your project? It can be found here,

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/mediation-networks

Direct download link : https://dl.google.com/dl/googleadmobadssdk/libadapteriad.zip

If not AdMob won't be able to serve iAds via their mediation SDK.

Comment: Yes, I added this.. Do I need to put it in a special place in my project or reference it somehow? I simply put it into my resources folder. Will that suffice?

Comment: I think you've also correctly set the linker flags as well (according to admob integration guide). According to their documentation there's no need to place it in a special place. However have you enabled all the iAd related features as well?Enabling iAd from ITC and , adding relevant framework to your project?

Comment: I've done all of those things. Linker flags, ITC enabling iAd, all relevant frameworks are there as well. I can fully implement iAd on it's own and i get test ads and everything..but as soon as I try and use the AdMob mediation I never see a single iAd